# Can I run several distros on one install?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, users

I'm still a pretty fresh Linux-user but I'm having a look at the Netbook-variants these days.

In fact I am as of now running on one Asus EEE:

- Jolicloud
- Maverick Netbook Edition
- Maverick Pristine
- Quimo 4 Kids

(This question submitted via Jolicloud.)

But I wonder if I'm doing this all wrong. Is it somehow possible to install Ubuntu Proper *once* and have different variants for different users?

Comment: This is probably better asked on: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

If you want to have the netbook edition, ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu, and similar setups for different users, then yes.

Just install the `*buntu-desktop` of choice, then have the user choose which desktop environment they want to use on login. However if you want to have JoliCloud, Mint, etc, then no, you cannot do this (at least not without chanting and doing the rain dance).

Comment: All of the above are Ubuntu-based though, even if their names don't give it away. Would that mean I could do what you describe?

Comment: Why I wouldn't suggest the ubuntu based Distros, is because they make underlying changes to the default settings, so essentially it's an all or nothing situation. For example, if you install the packages that make Mint, **Mint**, you won't be able to log into "ubuntu-desktop", until you remove those packages again.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not run several distros in one install. The closest you can get to that ideal is by multi-booting multiple distros (*info here: http://reddevil62-techhead.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-edit-grub-menu-to-dual-boot.html*) or by using a virtual machine for the other distros.

Comment: as a side note, running a virtual machine on a netbook is like using a sledgehammer to drive in a nail. Its slow, cumbersome, and has the potential to leave you with a sore thumb.

Comment: I'm currently running the distros side by side and selecting which distro to run at boot. Sounds like that's about as good as it gets then.